# R, why are these assignments' results different

Tags: r, function, matrix, assignment-operator

I am a beginner in R. I have a question on the following code.

```
f <- function(x,y){
  x+y[1]+y[2]
}

y <- matrix(1:8, ncol=2);y
x <- 1:4
i <- 1:4
v1 <- f(x[i], y[i,])
v2 <- NULL; v2[i] <- f(x[i], y[i,])
v3 <- NULL; for(i in 1:4){v3[i] <- f(x[i], y[i,])}
v1; v2; v3
```

The results are the same for v1 and v2. And v3 is what I want. But why can't I just use commands for v1 or v2? Why are they different? Is there any way to modify v1 or v2 a little bit to get the desired results? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your function `f` doesn't vectorize in the second argument.  You can see what is happening if you explicitly evaluate the addends inside the function:

```
> x[i]
[1] 1 2 3 4
> y[i,][1]
[1] 1
> y[i,][2]
[1] 2
```

So you can see, `f(x[i],y[i,])` is the same as evaluating `1:4 + 1 + 2`:

```
> 1:4 + 1 + 2
[1] 4 5 6 7
> f(x[i],y[i,])
[1] 4 5 6 7
```

If you are expecting a matrix in the second argument, you can write a vectorized version of the function, as described by @James.  Another option is to cast `y` as a data frame:

```
> f(x,data.frame(y))
  X1
1  7
2 10
3 13
4 16
```

The reason this works is that a data frame is represented as a list of columns, while a matrix is represented as an array with a dimension attribute.  So `y[1]` will give you the first element of `y` whereas `data.frame(y)[1]` will give you the first column:

```
> y[1]
[1] 1
> data.frame(y)[1]
  X1
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your implementation of `f`. The way the matrix subsetting works means you are returning the same matrix and always choosing the first two elements for each value in x.

If you write it in a more vectorised way it will work as you intend:

```
f2 <- function(x,y) x+y[,1]+y[,2]
f2(x,y)
[1]  7 10 13 16
```